# how to reduce amount of data in neo4j query?

Tags: api, rest, neo4j

when requesting data over [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org), as in, say,

```
curl -i -XPOST -d'{ "query" : "start n=node(*) return n" }' 
  -H "accept:application/json;stream=true" 
  -H content-type:application/json 
  http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
```

i get, as documented, a response like this:

```
{
  "columns" : [ "n" ],
  "data" : [ [ {
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out",
    "data" : {
    },
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/traverse/{returnType}",
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties/{key}",
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/properties",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in",
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships",
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/all",
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
  } ], [ {
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/out",
    "data" : {
      "glyph" : "一",
      "~isa" : "glyph"
    },
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/traverse/{returnType}",
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/properties/{key}",
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1",
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/properties",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/in",
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships",
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/all",
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
  } ], [ {
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/out",
    "data" : {
      "~isa" : "LPG",
      "LPG" : "1"
    },
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/traverse/{returnType}",
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/properties/{key}",
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2",
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/properties",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/in",
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships",
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/all",
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
  } ], [ {
```

and so on and on. the URLs delivered with each node are certainly well meant, but they also occupy a major portion of the data transmitted. they're also highly redundant and not what i', after with my query. is there any way to drop all of that `traverse`, 
`all_typed_relationships`, 
`property`, 
`self`, 
`properties`, 
`outgoing_typed_relationships`, 
`incoming_relationships`, 
`extensions`, 
`create_relationship`, 
`paged_traverse`, 
`all_relationships`, 
`incoming_typed_relationships`
jazz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to specify the properties you want returned in the `return` statement. Like:

```
return id(n), n.glyph;
```

Comment: i'll wait a day or so for someone to tell us about an imminent API update before accepting your contribution, but judging from my best knowledge this is the correct answer.

Comment: There actually is a discussion in the github issues about improving this from just recently. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/414